# Python: plotting time series data with two dependent date columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, bokeh, seaborn

I'm a bit of a novice with Python and I've been googling this for about an hour now and can't seem to get anywhere - has anyone had this kind of problem before and managed told solve it?

I'm trying to plot a time series data set with 1 metric across two date fields, which are both related.  For example, column A is the date, column B is the time slice within that date (ordinal)

Here is an example of my data.

```
        date         period         variable
2 2016-08-01  00:00 - 00:30         1
3 2016-08-01  00:30 - 01:00         2
4 2016-08-01  01:00 - 01:30         3
5 2016-08-01  01:30 - 02:00         4
6 2016-08-01  02:00 - 02:30         5
```

So I would want my x axis to show a combination of column A and column B, with column C on my y axis.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you combine the date and period into a string formatted the way you want and use it as a tick label?

Comment: if i did that would it still consider it as an ordinal label and plot my dates in the correct order?

Comment: In matplotlib, you solve that by creating a list of consecutive integers/numbers to use as the x data then use the text as tick labels.  There are examples in [the Gallery](https://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_demo_rotation.html).  There are also Q&A's here on SO that use that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution will of course depend on where the data comes from. Since we do not have this information, lets start with some list with dates as strings.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = [["2016-08-01",  "00:00 - 00:30",1],
     ["2016-08-01",  "00:30 - 01:00",2],
     ["2016-08-01",  "01:00 - 01:30",3],
     ["2016-08-01",  "01:30 - 02:00",4],
     ["2016-08-01",  "02:00 - 02:30",5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=["date", "period", "variable"])
# split "period" column into start and stop
df['starttime'], df['stoptime'] = df['period'].str.split(' - ', 1).str
# create new column with date and starttime
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['starttime'])
#create new dataframe with datetime as index and variable as only column
df2 = df[["datetime","variable"]]
df2.set_index("datetime",inplace=True)

#plot step function
df2.plot(drawstyle="steps-post")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks - I'm hoping this is the solution but I'm just having some errors with my data ('Unknown string format') - I'll report back when I've fixed them!

Comment: Yes here I assumed that the first two columns are strings. If they are not, this will not work. But since you have given no information about the datatype of your columns, this was my best guess. The more information we have, the bigger the chances of providing an accurate solution.

Comment: yep, sorry I don't actually know how to give detailed information about my data! dtypes just shows it as an object and I dont know how to get a greaterlevel of detail on it. I've been trying to google ways to find out more about it, but from what I can tell they're just strings. at surface value it looks exactly the same as the data set you created above. Interestingly it works for the first 20 rows of data fine, so there must be some inconsistency within the column.

Comment: `df.info()` gives you some information. Otherwise the way to go would probably to start at the point where you read the data into pandas. Where does it come from? How is it read in?

Comment: It seems to work for the first 400k rows but not beyond that - so can't be the formatting, but something within the data itself. It's a csv that came in via pandas csv reader. `Data columns (total 6 columns):
date            977324 non-null object
period          977326 non-null object
var1      977327 non-null float64
var2    977327 non-null float64
starttime       977326 non-null object
stoptime        977325 non-null object`

Comment: Ok, so if it works for part of the data, the approach here is fine. You now have a totally different problem of sanitizing data. The idea would be to find out at which data row it fails (or is it just the last one?) and give an example of some working rows and non-working rows; best do that in a new question, because the actual problem is unrelated to plotting etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to combine date and end of period as timestamp and then plot the timestamp vs your value on a scatter plot.

If duration of the periods is important to you, then you can create two datapoints for each observation, start and end of period and connect them with a line segment. This way you are not loosing information about period lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib:

y data:

```
>>> var
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Make text labels

```
>>> labels
['2016-08-01#00:00 - 00:30', '2016-08-01#00:30 - 01:00','2016-08-01#01:00 - 01:30',
 '2016-08-01#01:30 - 02:00', '2016-08-01#02:00 - 02:30']
```

Create x values for the plot

```
>>> x = list(range(len(labels)))
>>> x
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Plot x and y, assign labels to the x-ticks

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, var)
plt.xticks(x, labels, rotation='vertical')
```